# ¿Como recargo el valor de un select en HTML?

Tags: html, laravel

tengo el siguiente problema

En mi página web tengo dos tipos de select, uno para seleccionar una región y otro para seleccionar algún tipo de filtro, cuando recargo la página con un botón para obtener los datos, el select se reinicia, dando el valor por defecto y no el seleccionado, me gustaría saber como lo puedo hacer, estos son mis ambos select

```
<select class="form-control" style="text-align: center" name="seleccion" id="seleccion" required>
                            <option selected>Seleccione Región</option>
                            <option value="1">Acceso General</option>
                            <option value="2">Segundo Piso</option>
                            <option value="3">Patio de Comidas</option>
                        </select>
```

```
<select class="form-control" style="text-align: center" name="opcion" id="opcion" required>
                            <option selected>Seleccione filtro</option>
                            <option value="1">Filtro por Día</option>
                            <option value="2">Filtro por Segmento</option>
                        </select>
```

Todo esto está dentro de un formulario con método GET

Comment: Puedes utilizar Ajax, que hará la petición sin necesidad de recargar la pagina, por lo que mantendrá la opción seleccionada.

Comment: Solo ocupas regresar el mismo request del select en la respuesta cuando recargas la pagina, request()->get('opcion'), si es una peticion get puedes tambien usar el facada request('nombre_del_campo')